# Thread.Abort errors that happen on Server.Transfer

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting a couple errors in some cases when a `Server.Transfer` happens.

Thread was being aborted.

```
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)     
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)     
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)     
at App._Default.TransferToCheckLoginPage() in blahblah\Default.aspx.vb:line 31     
at App._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in blahblah\Default.aspx.vb:line 18
```

Thread was being aborted.

```
at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()     
at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)     
at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()     
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)     
at App.ASPX.ck_login.TransferToStartPage() in blahblah\ck_login.aspx.vb:line 45     
at App.ASPX.ck_login.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in blahblah\ck_login.aspx.vb:line 33
```

now the strange thing is that the transfer completes (on some occasions it does not, which is why I am interested in this error)

What ASP.Net lifecycle events happen during a server.transfer?

In one case, its happening when Server.Transfer() is pointed to an html page that has the extension .aspx (There is no page directive) but an inline asp call <% %> (and it has a frame that points to a normal .aspx page)

As this is a currently deployed app, I'm not looking to do too many changes to it if I don't have to.  I'm more interested in knowing what in the `Server.Transfer` process would abort a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. You can safely ignore it

> This behavior is by design.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629

Comment: ok, it says that a workaround is *Server.Execute*.  What does *Server.Execute* do differently?

Comment: Server.Execute comes back to the calling page afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentaiton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx):

> The page transferred to should be another .aspx page. For instance, a
>   transfer to an .asp or .asmx page is not valid. The Transfer method
>   preserves the QueryString and Form collections.
>
> Transfer calls End, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception upon
>   completion.

The same is true for Response.Redirect (by default, although you can override this.)  You can ignore these errors.

*However, even though the processing ends on the original page, processing should continue on the page that was transferred to*.

Answer (score 0):

As I know during `Server.Transfer` system throws Thread abort exception, and starts to execute new page cycle. On other hand `Response.Redirect`, this method ends response correctly and send status 302 to the client,

```
HTTP 1.0 302 Object Moved 
Location: http://www.google.com
```

than client requests new page that was scpecifed in response `location`.